# How make month wise partitioning in existing mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

I have a table with hundreds of thousands of records. How to partition the table, month-wise?

Answer (score 1):

You can `ALTER TABLE` to create new [PARITIONS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-range.html) on it.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name PARTITION BY RANGE (MONTH(date_column)
(
  PARTITION JAN VALUES LESS THAN (2),
  PARTITION FEB VALUES LESS THAN (3),
  ...
  PARTITION DEC VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

Comment: @Omesh : Please have a look and answer. If your answer will be helping me. I am sure; "I Know how to accept answer :)". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880154/how-do-i-create-a-partition-for-every-month-of-the-current-year