# Partition using Month of TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql

I have a table  employees which i need to partition based on the month of timestamp. I have tried some types buts not working.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
id INT NOT NULL,
fname VARCHAR(30),
lname VARCHAR(30),
hired DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
separated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
job_code INT,
store_id INT
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ( date_format(separated,'%m') ) (
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (01),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (02),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (03),
 ----
PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (04)
```

);

when am creating this table it is showing that **this partition function is not allowed**
if am using **MONTH(seperated)** it works for DATE type but it returns **invalid default value for seperated**

Comment: Never heard of partitioning, but browsing through the docs I found `PARTITION BY HASH(MONTH(col))`, here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html. Perhaps it helps?

Comment: @Rahul - have you received the answer yet? Please share. (Might as well close the topic .)

Comment: @Rahul so the answer below dosesn't solve you problem, now would you care to elaborate a little bit more about what you want to achieve, as the monthly partitioning can be achieved by the answer below, we use it in our production system, it seems to work well. with ID and Timestamp as our primary keys.

Comment: @Joddy Sorry for the delay.. As per my requirement i want to partition the fields base on month only. As per my understanding the input u provided has to be changed yearly. i want ot avoid that for a more generalized one

Comment: @Rahul Check this resource - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862051/how-make-month-wise-partitioning-in-existing-mysql-table

Comment: @Rahul - Using List Partitioning - http://deepakmodi2006.blogspot.in/2009/08/partitioning-table-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 1):

How we do it in our project (may be not the right way, but works for us) - (MySQL 5.1.60)

> PARTITION p201 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-01-01')), 
>   PARTITION p202 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-02-01')), 
>   PARTITION p203 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-03-01')), 
>   PARTITION p204 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-04-01')), 
>   PARTITION p205 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-05-01')), 
>   PARTITION p206 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-06-01')), 
>   PARTITION p207 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-07-01')), 
>   PARTITION p208 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-08-01')), 
>   PARTITION p209 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-09-01')), 
>   PARTITION p210 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-10-01')), 
>   PARTITION p211 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-11-01')), 
>   PARTITION p212 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-12-01'))

That is partitioning for Complete year of 2012