# How do I create a partition for every month of the current year

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I want to partition my data by "MONTH"

I am trying this,

```
ALTER TABLE t1 PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)))(
PARTITION JAN VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-02-01')),
PARTITION FEB VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-03-01')),
PARTITION MAR VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-04-01')),
PARTITION APR VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-05-01')),
PARTITION MAY VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-06-01')),
PARTITION JUN VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-07-01')),
PARTITION JUL VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-08-01')),
PARTITION AUG VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-09-01')),
PARTITION SEP VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-10-01')),
PARTITION `OCT` VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-11-01')),
PARTITION NOV VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-12-01')),
PARTITION `DEC` VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2014-01-01'))
```

);

```
transaction_date INT NOT NULL //store date by UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Error Code: 1564
This partition function is not allowed

How do I create a partition for every month of the current year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56810) or limitation.

For Monthly partitioning you may try this:

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79f11/3)**

```
ALTER TABLE t1 PARTITION BY RANGE(transaction_date)(
PARTITION JAN VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-02-01')),
PARTITION FEB VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-03-01')),
PARTITION MAR VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-04-01')),
PARTITION APR VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-05-01')),
PARTITION MAY VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-01')),
PARTITION JUN VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-07-01')),
PARTITION JUL VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-01')),
PARTITION AUG VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-09-01')),
PARTITION SEP VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-01')),
PARTITION `OCT` VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-11-01')),
PARTITION NOV VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-12-01')),
PARTITION `DEC` VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01'))
);
```

If you have a column having DATE as data type then you may try this for Daily partitioning inside monthly paritioning:
Try using [sub-partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-subpartitions.html) in MySQL

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50c5f/2)**

```
ALTER TABLE t1 
PARTITION BY RANGE( MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date) )
SUBPARTITION BY HASH( DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)) )
SUBPARTITIONS 31 (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (3),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (4),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (5),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (7),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (8),
    PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (9),
    PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
    PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
    PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (12),
    PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

Comment: @ Omesh ! Thx for the reply but m facing the same issue "Error Code: 1564 This partition function is not allowed". Your example on SQL Fiddle is gud. Do you have any idea about this Error ?